# How do I set emacs to use 3 spaces instead of tabs in verilog mode?

Tags: emacs, verilog, emacs23

I am pretty new to emacs (using version 23.3) and I wanted to set the default tab key to insert 3 spaces instead of a tab character in verilog mode. I did find a number of posts regarding this in stack overflow. Some of them are: -

[How To Force spaces instead of tabs regardless of major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901830/how-to-force-spaces-instead-of-tabs-regardless-of-major-mode)

[Why might my Emacs use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885411/why-might-my-emacs-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

[Emacs global configuration of tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165503/emacs-global-configuration-of-tabs)

But they do not seem to work in verilog mode. This is how my .emacs file looks like

```
(custom-set-variables      
 '(tab-stop-list ('(3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96 99 102 105 108 111 114 117 120)))
 '(verilog-case-indent 3)    
 '(verilog-indent-level-directive 0)
 '(verilog-indent-level 3)    
 '(verilog-tab-always-indent nil))
(custom-set-faces
  )
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 
          '(lambda () 
             (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
             (setq tab-width 3)))

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 3)
(setq-default standard-indent 3)
```

If I try to edit a text file, the setup works perfectly and inserts 3 spaces instead of a tab. However it still inserts a tab character when I try to edit a verilog file (.v). I can select the entire text and do M-x untabify to get the required result but is there another direct solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the hook you should use `setq` instead of `setq-default`, so you need to rewrite your hook to something like:

```
(defun my-verilog-hook ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
    (setq tab-width 3))
 (add-hook 'verilog-mode-hook 'my-verilog-hook)
```

P.S. it's better to use dedicated functions in hooks, as it's easier to change them, and you can also remove them from hooks

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I still have the problem. Browsing through the different options I do find 4 option named 1) Verilog auto hook, 2) Verilog before auto hook 3) verilog delete auto hook and 4) verilog before delete auto hook. Should I change these values for it to work?\

Comment: That's very strange - I just checked this function once again (gnu emacs 24 from bzr), and when I set `indent-tabs-mode` to `t`, then I get tabs in source code, but when I set it to `nil`, then I get space...
Could you check - maybe you have some hook, that is part of Emacs init code? Which functions are listed in `verilog-mode-hook` ?

Comment: Ok I checked the `verilog-mode-hook` it says `my-verilog-hook` THe problem still persists. Btb I am using emacs version 23.3, downloaded from [emacs official site](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/). Might be a bug that got fixed in version 24. And yes I did get a temporary work around [here](http://www.veripool.org/issues/345-Verilog-mode-can-t-get-untabify-on-save-to-work) This seems to work fine. Tabs will be converted to spaces when I save the file

Comment: I also checked code for verilog-mode - it doesn't use indent-tabs-mode directly, so it should be handled by underlying mode... But that's fine that `untabify` works for you